# javascript regular expression remove complete words only

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to use regular expression on javascript to remove some uneeded words.
for ex., my base strings are
1. "David Guetta avi!"
2. "David Guetta avi bla bla"
3. "avi of David Guetta"

I want to remove the "avi", as you see, in the 1st string the avi wrapped by space and exclamation mark, the 2nd string wrapped by spaces and the 3rd wrapped by space in the right side only.

If I use .replace(/avi/s,''); it will remove the avi also from David (will be Dd).
I need help with write regexp which will remove the specific word which not wrapped or wrapped by symbols (also spaces slashes whatever).

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you also want to remove the whitespace adjacent to it? What about non-whitespace, non-word characters like `!`, remove them too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the word boundary special character?
So the regex would be:

```
\b<word>\b
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
\W\avi\W{0,1}
```

The `\W` stands for any non-word character.

You can also try

```
[^a-zA-Z]avi[^a-zA-Z]{0,1}
```

where `[^a-zA-Z]` is anything **not** in `a-zA-Z`.

Comment: `\W{0,1}` is the same as `\W?` :)

Comment: @Jack No, `\W{0,1}` means zero or one character, whereas `\W` is exactly one character. Actually I think you should use it without the `{0,1}` :)

Comment: @Jack I edited to remove the `{0,1}` modifiers from the first non-word character. I think you should leave it for the second non-word character or you won't remove `avi` at the end of a string: `David Guetta avi`

Comment: I didn't ask a question, I made a statement; i.e. the `?` was part of it :)

Comment: @Jack Oooh, just saw that :) subtle difference!

Comment: 10x, but its not working well for "avi of David Guetta", i think the best way is the
"mystring.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').replace(/\bavi\b/,'');"

Answer (score 0):

I've combined @Evan answer into symbol removal regexp + double space removal and the final answer is:

`mystring.replace(/[^\w\s]|\bavi\b|\s{2,}/gi,'');`

thank you all :)